# Gutenberg custom block, function/attributes not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress-gutenberg

I receive the console error

```
ReferenceError: selectImage is not defined
    at edit (index.js?fb2e:95)
```

I thought `selectImage` was defined in the following Gutenberg block:

```
/**
 * Block dependencies
 */
import icon from './icon';
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Internal block libraries
 */
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const {
    RichText,
    MediaUpload,
    BlockControls,
    BlockAlignmentToolbar,
} = wp.editor

/**
 * Register block
 */
export default registerBlockType(
    'jsforwpblocks/heroblock',
    {
        title: __( 'Hero Block', 'jsforwpblocks' ),
        description: __( 'Large block with hero image, text and buttons', 'jsforwpblocks' ),
        category: 'common',
        icon: {
            background: 'rgba(254, 243, 224, 0.52)',
            src: icon,
        },   
        keywords: [
            __( 'Banner', 'jsforwpblocks' ),
            __( 'Call to Action', 'jsforwpblocks' ),
            __( 'Message', 'jsforwpblocks' ),
        ],
        attributes: {
            message: {
                type: 'array',
                source: 'children',
                selector: '.message-body',
            },
            blockAlignment: {
                type: 'string',
                default: 'wide',
            },
            imgUrl: {
                type: 'string',
                default: 'http://placehold.it/500'
            }
        },
        getEditWrapperProps( { blockAlignment } ) {
            if ( 'left' === blockAlignment || 'right' === blockAlignment || 'full' === blockAlignment ) {
                return { 'data-align': blockAlignment };
            }
        },
        selectImage(value) {
            console.log(value);
            setAttributes({
                imgUrl: value.sizes.full.url,
            })
        },
        edit: props => {
            const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment }, className, setAttributes } = props;
            const onChangeMessage = message => { setAttributes( { message } ) };

            return (
                <div className={ className }>
                    <BlockControls>
                        <BlockAlignmentToolbar
                            value={ blockAlignment }
                            onChange={ blockAlignment => setAttributes( { blockAlignment } ) }
                        />
                    </BlockControls>
                    <RichText
                        tagName="div"
                        multiline="p"
                        placeholder={ __( 'Add your custom message', 'jsforwpblocks' ) }
                        onChange={ onChangeMessage }
                        value={ message }
                    />
                    <div className="media">
                        <MediaUpload 
                            onSelect={selectImage}
                            render={ ({open}) => {
                                return <img 
                                    src={attributes.imgUrl}
                                    onClick={open}
                                    />;
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        },
        save: props => {
            const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment, imgUrl } } = props;
            return (
                <div
                    className={classnames(
                        `align${blockAlignment}`
                    )}
                    style={backgroundImage={imgUrl}}
                >
                    <h2>{ __( 'Call to Action', 'jsforwpblocks' ) }</h2>
                    <div class="message-body">
                        { message }
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        },
    },
);
```

**EDIT**

If I move the function down into the edit function, the error disappears:

```
    edit: props => {
        const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment }, className, setAttributes } = props;
        const onChangeMessage = message => { setAttributes( { message } ) };

        function selectImage(value) {
            console.log(value);
            setAttributes({
                imgUrl: value.sizes.full.url,
            })
        }

        return (
            <div className={ className }>
```

However, I receive a new error:

```
ReferenceError: attributes is not defined
    at Object.render (index.js:101)
```

Line 101 is the last line of:

```
    save: props => {
        const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment, imgUrl } } = props;
        return (
            <div
                className={classnames(
```

The [updated code is here](https://pastebin.com/VYndyYNx) (pastebin.com).

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add `className` in `save` to your `props` object destructering like you did in `edit`:

`const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment, imgUrl }, className } = props;`

Two more things:

1. A few lines down you're using `class`, I'd change this to `className` as well
2. If I use `classnames` in a custom block I always add it to my imports:

`import classnames from 'lodash/classnames'`

Haven't actually tried if it would work without importing it.

Comment: Thx for your help. When I add `className` to `const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment, imgUrl }, className } = props;` it becomes greyed out indicating it is not being used. I've changed class to className, and installed lodash and imported classnames from 'lodash/classnames', but the same error remains.

Comment: I was wrong with `className` in this case as it's not the `className` from the props object but JSX' equivalent for HTMLs `class`, still not sure with lodash's `classnames` though – if it works properly without importing it...

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly checked your block (the original version from pastebin - without my former edits) in my setup and I had the same error. But the error doesn't refer to `save` but to `edit`. What helped was adding `imgUrl` to your attributes destructering in `edit` (same as in `save`):

```
const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment, imgUrl }, className, setAttributes } = props;
```

and then only use `imgUrl` in your `MediaUpload` `return` `src` like that:

```
return <img src={imgUrl} onClick={open} />;
```

Comment: On more thing: I had deprecation warnings for the internal components from `wp.editor`, as they have been moved to `wp.blockEditor`. You should change this accordingly. And maybe add `wp-block-editor` to your `wp_register_script` dependencies array in your plugins PHP as well.

Comment: I made that change and the same error occurs. [This is my new file](https://pastebin.com/ZagD4G25).

Comment: Hm, strange. If I test your new file I don't get the `attributes` error anymore, but I get other ones. The only thing I have changed is commenting out the `style.scss` import and the `icon` import (as I don't have these in my setup). But this shouldn't make a difference. The errors I get are for how you implement the inline styles in `save`. I'll post another answer with a complete replacement for your save function. This work for me in the backend and frontend without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to your second file on Pastebin try the following replacement for your save function:

```
save: props => {
            const { attributes: { message, blockAlignment, imgUrl } } = props;
            const divStyle = {
                backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
              };
            return (
                <div
                    className={classnames(
                        `align${blockAlignment}`
                    )}
                    style={divStyle}
                >
                    <h2>{ __( 'Call to Action', 'jsforwpblocks' ) }</h2>
                    <div className="message-body">
                        { message }
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        },
```

And the `classnames` import actually only worked like that (but might depend on how you set your dependencies):

```
import classnames from 'classnames'
```